# Maximum determinant of $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, contest-math, determinant

Good one guys! 
I'm studying to the maths olympiads in my college and I ran to the following problem:

What is the possible matrix $3 \times 3$, that you can write using digits from $0 $ to $9$, (you can repeat them), that gives you the maximum determinant?

I got by brute force the matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
0 && 9 && 9\\
9 && 0 && 9 \\
9 && 9 && 0\\
\end{pmatrix}

Are there any other ways to do it besides brute force?

I looked about Hadamard maximum determinant theorem but I did not get how to apply it.

Thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 3):

The determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix is just the area of the parallelepiped spanned by it's column vectors. If you think about the problem geometrically, I think it's a bit easier to see why your answer should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, consider the $n \times n$ case.
Since the determinant is a linear function of the entries in any given row or column, it's clear that there is an optimal solution with all entries $0$ or $9$.  Dividing by $9$, you have an $n \times n$ $0-1$ matrix with maximum determinant, and that [corresponds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_maximal_determinant_problem) to a normalized solution of the  $(n+1) \times (n+1)$  Hadamard maximal determinant problem.

Comment: Why does being linear imply there is an optimal solution with all $0$ or $9$s? Couldn't a row have some large entries and some small entries? You might be able to say every row and column needs to have at least one 9, but I don't even think that's true: since everything must be an INTEGER, you can't scale rows and columns arbitrarily.

Comment: I didn't mean all $0$'s or all $9$'s, I mean each entry is either $0$ or $9$.  Consider e.g. the first column, and fix all other entries at the values for some optimal solution.  The determinant is a linear function of the matrix elements $a_{11}, \ldots, a_{n1}$.  If the coefficient of $a_{i1}$ in this linear function is positive,  you maximize the determinant by taking $a_{i1} = 9$.  If negative, you maximize the determinant by taking $a_{i1} = 0$.  If $0$, it doesn't matter what $a_{i1}$ is, so you may as well take it to be $0$ or $9$.

Answer (score 0):

For a $3\times 3$ matrix you can also easily see it by using [The rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus).